# How can I find out if my server has IPMI of some sort?

Tags: linux, debian, ipmi, ipmitool

I've never seen a Linux server I admin. How can I find out if it has IPMI of some sort installed?

I tried answering my own question by installing ipmitool:

```
Setting up ipmitool (1.8.9-2) ...
Starting IPMI event daemon ipmievdipmievd: using pidfile /var/run/ipmievd.pid0
Could not open device at /dev/ipmi0 or /dev/ipmi/0 or /dev/ipmidev/0: No such  file or directory
Unable to open interface
failed!
invoke-rc.d: initscript ipmievd, action "start" failed.
```

was the answer. Can I find out what the ISP uses to remote-control the server or how the ISP probably hooked it into their remote-management HTML panel?

Comment: If it's a VPC there's no way you're getting IPMI access (unless there's a hypervisor system out there that integrates). If it's a dedicated server they're still going to be very reluctant to give you that level of access.

Comment: It's a dedicated Debian box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's Red Hat, just do `rpm -qa|grep ipmi`. OpenIPMI would be the most likely install, or one of the proprietary ones (like hpIPMI). There should be an equivalent command on `.deb` systems and Solaris boxes as well.

Comment: It's Debian: dpkg -l | grep ipmi \n
rc  ipmitool                        1.8.9-2                    utility for IPMI control with kernel driver \n 
ii  libopenipmi0                    2.0.14-1                   Intelligent Platform Management Interface -

Comment: I wish i could help more, i'm a red hat guy. I see the OpenIPMI library is there, but not the explicit package. See if apt-get install openipmi works (the package name may not be correct). Its possible they're not using IPMI if the HTML management utility is just reporting stuff from MIB-II and the host mib in SNMP. If you're trying to figure out how they're monitoring your box SNMP may be a good place to look.

Comment: Although "apt-get install openipmi" did work, I now have it on the system and it doesn't do much. I think the libopeipmi lib was just left-over from the ipmitool install done earlier... When my ISP uses SNMP, is it save for me to poke around in it? Is there a save snmp command I can shoot at the server's localhost while being SSH'd into it?

Comment: You can install snmp-utils (again, check the package name), and then walk the available snmp information by using the snmpwalk command.

Comment: This answer is just incorrect. Question is how to tell whether the server physically has an IPMI system, not whether your O/S has an IPMI package installed.

Answer (score 25):

From [FreeIPMI's FAQ](http://www.gnu.org/software/freeipmi/freeipmi-faq.html) section: [7. Does my system support IPMI?](http://www.gnu.org/software/freeipmi/freeipmi-faq.html#Does-my-system-support-IPMI_003f).

> ### Does my system support IPMI?
>
> Unfortunately, there are no universally defined mechanisms for
> determining if a system supports IPMI via Inband communication.
> Assuming IPMI is set up correctly for over LAN communication, a fairly
> reliable mechanism exists out-of-band. Here are some suggestions.
>
> 1. FreeIPMI’s `ipmi-locate` can be used to determine if IPMI can be found on your system. Users are cautioned though, the failure to
>    discover IPMI via ipmi-locate is not sufficient to disprove that IPMI
>    exists on your system. Your system may not publish such information or
>    may expect clients to communicate at default locations.
> 2. `dmidecode` may be similarly used to probe for devices that support IPMI on your system. You may grep for IPMI or specify the IPMI DMI
>    type on the command line.
>
>    ```
>     # > dmidecode --type 38
>     # dmidecode 2.10 SMBIOS 2.5 present.
>
>     Handle 0x0049, DMI type 38, 18 bytes IPMI Device Information
>             Interface Type: KCS (Keyboard Control Style)
>             Specification Version: 2.0
>             I2C Slave Address: 0x10
>             NV Storage Device: Not Present
>             Base Address: 0x0000000000000CA2 (I/O)
>             Register Spacing: Successive Byte Boundaries
>    ```
> 3. FreeIPMI’s `ipmi-ping` can be used to see if a machine has an IPMI service at a specific host/IP address. For more wide scale IPMI
>    discovery, the `ipmi-detectd` daemon and `ipmi-detect` tool can be used.
>
> Again, the failure to find an IPMI supported device is not sufficient
> to show lack of IPMI support.
>
> Ultimately, some amount of information from product documents or trial
> and error may be necessary to determine if IPMI is supported on your
> system.